# how to assign parent class public variable to child class public variable in php

Tags: php, oop

I have created two class, Assigning public class variable to child class variable but not working properly.But the same variable assign working inside function correctly.I didn't get proper reason why like that.Please check below example.

```
      <?php
          Class pratice{
            public $a=4;
           }
         Class child extends pratice{
            //public $b =$this->a;//getting error with this assigment
            public function getValue(){
            $this->b = $this->a;//working fine with this
            echo $this->b;
           }
         }
        $obj = new child();
        $obj->getValue();
       ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$this->a` is an expression referencing an active object. Which is why it cannot be used in the class declaration itself (all static at this point), but only in methods (when an object is instantiated).

Comment: PD of [declare property as object?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2202995) / [Syntax error while defining an array as a property of a class](//stackoverflow.com/q/9225632) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `$this` refers to an instance of the class, so until you create an instance of the class, `$this` isn't available.

You would have to do it in the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), when it can reference itself in a non-static context.

```
class Child extends Practice
{

    public $b;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->b = $this->a;
        echo $this->b;
    }
}
```